# How to simplify complex long nested if else statements in C#

Tags: c#

I have the function shown below that calculates the tax value based on five input parameters. 
For each combination of input parameters there is a matching 'condition' which is simply the return statement, e.g. if the input parameters are:

```
nationality == "German" and 
netIncome == 45000 and 
(birthDate >= 01.01.1950 && birthDate < 01.01.1960) and 
childrenCount == 1 
then tax value is 0.15%
```

the if else statements can get very very long and nested if we consider all input parameter combinations.

```
public static decimal GetTax(int netIncome, string nationality, DateTime birthDate, int childrenCount, bool handicapped)
{
    if (nationality == "DE")
    {
        if (handicapped)
        {
            // condition1
            return 0;
        }

        if (birthDate >= new DateTime(1930, 1, 1) && birthDate < new DateTime(1936,1,1))
        {
            if (childrenCount == 1)
            {
                // condition2
                return 0.05m;
            }
            else
            {
                // other conditions
            }
        }
        else if(birthDate >= new DateTime(1950, 1, 1))
        {
            if (netIncome >= 30000 && netIncome < 40000)
            {
                if (childrenCount == 1)
                {
                    // condition3
                    return 0.15m;
                }
                else if (childrenCount == 2 || childrenCount == 3)
                {
                    // other conditions
                    return Convert.ToDecimal(netIncome * 0.10);
                }
                else
                {
                    // other conditions
                }
            }
            if (netIncome >= 40000 && netIncome < 50000)
            {
                if (childrenCount >= 1 && childrenCount < 3)
                {
                    // other conditions
                    return Convert.ToDecimal(netIncome * 0.17);
                }
                else if (childrenCount >= 3 || childrenCount < 5)
                {
                    // other conditions
                    return Convert.ToDecimal(netIncome * 0.16);
                }
                else
                {
                    // other conditions
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    else if (nationality == "FR")
    {

    }
    else if (nationality == "IT")
    {

    }

    // just to satisfy the compiler
    throw new Exception("The input parameters don't match any condition!");
}
```

**The question is: How to simplify the above if else statements to become a more understandable and easier to maintain code?**

I came up with a simple (I hope) solution that I would like to present:

**(1) I created a class called Condition shown below**

```
private class Condition
{
    private readonly decimal tax;
    private readonly Predicate<string> nationalityPredicate;
    private readonly Predicate<DateTime> birthDatePredicate;
    private readonly Predicate<int> childrenCountPredicate;
    private readonly Predicate<int> netIncomePredicate;
    private readonly Predicate<bool> handicappedPredicate;

    public Condition(decimal taxParameter, Predicate<string> nationality, Predicate<DateTime> birthDate, Predicate<int> netIncome, Predicate<int> childrenCount, Predicate<bool> handicapped)
    {
        this.tax = taxParameter;
        this.nationalityPredicate = new Predicate<string>(nationality);
        this.birthDatePredicate = new Predicate<DateTime>(birthDate);
        this.netIncomePredicate = new Predicate<int>(netIncome);
        this.childrenCountPredicate = new Predicate<int>(childrenCount);
        this.handicappedPredicate = new Predicate<bool>(handicapped);
    }

    public bool IsTrue(string nationality, DateTime birthDate, int netIncome, int childrenCount, bool handicapped)
    {
        if (this.nationalityPredicate(nationality))
        {
            if (this.birthDatePredicate(birthDate))
            {
                if (this.netIncomePredicate(netIncome))
                {
                    if (this.childrenCountPredicate(childrenCount))
                    {
                        if (this.handicappedPredicate(handicapped))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public decimal CalculateTax()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(this.tax);
        return this.tax;
    }
}
```

this class corresponds to one condition in the nested if else statements in the GetTax() function above. e.g. When the 5 input parameters are Nationality="DE", birthDate="01.01.1955", netIncome=35,000, childrenCount=1 and handicapped=false then the tax for this condition is 0.15

This class is used to break down long complex nested if else statements. 
For each return statement in the GetTax() function we use one Condition class instant.

**(2) I created the TaxCalculator class that uses the Condition class as an internal helper class as shown below**

```
    public class TaxCalculator
    {
        // List of conditions
        private readonly List<Condition> conditions = new List<Condition>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor. All the conditions are created and initialized here. 
        /// The conditions initialized in the constructor correspond to the nested if else statements in the GetTax() function.
        /// </summary>
        public TaxCalculator()
        {
            // This corresponds to Condition1 in the 'GetTax()' function
            Condition condition = new Condition(
                0,
                nationality => nationality == "DE",
                birthDate => true,
                netIncome => true,
                childrenCount => true,
                handicapped => handicapped);

            this.conditions.Add(condition);

            // This corresponds to Condition2 in the 'GetTax()' function 
            condition = new Condition(
                0.05m,
                nationality => nationality == "DE",
                birthDate => (birthDate >= new DateTime(1930, 1, 1)) && (birthDate < new DateTime(1936, 1, 1)),
                netIncome => true,
                childrenCount => childrenCount == 1,
                handicapped => !handicapped);

            this.conditions.Add(condition);

            // This corresponds to Condition3 in the 'GetTax()' function
            condition = new Condition(
                0.15m,
                nationality => nationality == "DE",
                birthDate => birthDate >= new DateTime(1950, 1, 1),
                netIncome => (netIncome >= 30000 && netIncome < 40000),
                childrenCount => childrenCount == 1,
                handicapped => !handicapped);

            this.conditions.Add(condition);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This function corresponds to the GetTax() function, it determines which Condition object corresponds
        /// to the input parameters.
        /// </summary>
        public decimal CalculateTax(string nationality, DateTime birthDate, int netIncome, int childrenCount, bool handicapped)
        {
            // iterate the conditions
            foreach (Condition c in this.conditions)
            {
                // check if the input parameters apply the current condition
                if (c.IsTrue(nationality, birthDate, netIncome, childrenCount, handicapped))
                {
                    // if yes, return the result of this condition
                    return c.CalculateTax();
                }
            }

            // in case of no matching condition raise an exception.
            throw new Exception("TaxCalculator class didn't match any condition for parameters...etc.");
        }
}
```

The TaxCalculator class corresponds to the long nested if else statements in the GetTax() function above.
The class creates Condition objects in the constructor using simple lambda expressions, each Condition object corresponds to one condition in the GetTax() function (marked with //Condition1, //Condition2 and //Condition3)

**(3) To calculate the tax for a given set of input parameters we do the following:**

```
    TaxCalculator taxCalculator = new TaxCalculator();

    // check for conditions

    // condition3
    decimal tax = taxCalculator.CalculateTax("DE", new DateTime(1985, 1, 1), 33000, 1, false);

    // condition2 
    tax = taxCalculator.CalculateTax("DE", new DateTime(1933, 1, 1), 0, 1, false);

    // condition1
    tax = taxCalculator.CalculateTax("DE", new DateTime(1977, 1, 1), 0, 0, true);
```

**Questions:**

- Is there a better and easier solution that provides easy maintenance?
- Any optimization or correction suggestions?

Comment: How about using ands along with your ifs, sicne you don't have an else condition on most things?

Comment: Might fit better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I removed the else(s) for simplicity only

Comment: This also seems like a question for the domain expert. For example, is it always the case that a person will *only* match one set of conditions? If not, it is important which order your conditions are applied in because you return after the first positive match. Also, is it possible to bucket the age ranges to simplify things?

Comment: one thing you can do is to take the contents of some of your if-statements and turn them into methods.  Even if you can't re-use the methods, your code will still tell a better story

Comment: This smells as something to be done by a business-rule-engine. I'm not claiming that such thing would make it easier...but at least the [WF-Rule engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349785.aspx) claims to be able to maintain rules without the need to recompile...

Comment: @Matt Burland
Yes, the nested if else that I try to simplify only have one return value for every input parameter set, this is why I take the first match.
What do you mean with: bucket the age ranges?

Comment: @Sam I am:
I considered this and ended up with very long method names, also the methods still cause the code to be nested and don't help in adjusting the logic if parameter values change or new parameters are added.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the first If like this :

```
public bool IsTrue(string nationality, DateTime birthDate, int netIncome, int childrenCount, bool handicapped)
{
    return (this.nationalityPredicate(nationality) && 
            this.birthDatePredicate(birthDate) &&
            this.netIncomePredicate(netIncome) &&
            this.childrenCountPredicate(childrenCount) &&
            this.handicappedPredicate(handicapped))
}
```

For the rest it's a classical rule checking engine, seems fine. Perhap's just invert the last throw exception. It's a matter of choice, but the exception is not the normal application flow IMHO. So you should throw exception if something is wrong, not if something is not wrong. Like :

```
public decimal CalculateTax(string nationality, DateTime birthDate, int netIncome, int childrenCount, bool handicapped)
{
    var result = this.condition.FirstOrDefault(c => c.IsTrue(nationality, birthDate, netIncome, childrenCount, handicapped));

    if(result == null) 
        throw new Exception("TaxCalculator class didn't match any condition for parameters...etc.");

    return result.CalculateTax();           
}
```

Perhap's just be careful with the name. "IsTrue" ? What is true ? What does it means from a business point of view or even technically ? I'm sure it's crystal clear for you, but not for someone who will have to maintain it, he will have to take a look at the method definition (in the best case, if not the entire rule engine) to understand what this "IsTrue" means. At least you have comment, but a good method name is, IMHO, way better than thousands lines of comments.